# Mongo push objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I want to push an object to specify name of fields rather than array. I tried $push but I lose informations about field's name inserted in the array.
My collection is :

```
  /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57614a7bd75df17df3013903"),
    "O":"aa",
    "D":"bb",
    "month":1,
    "year":2015,
    "freq":5
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57614a7bd75df17df3013904"),
    "O":"aa",
    "D":"bb",
    "month":2,
    "year":2015,
    "freq":5
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57614a7bd75df17df3013905"),
    "O":"aa",
    "D":"bb",
    "month":1,
    "year":2016,
    "freq":5
}
```

I want to store all freq corresponding to fields : O and D.
Here is my expected output :

```
    "_id" : ...,
    "O" : "aa",
    "D" : "bb",
    "freq" : {
        "2015" : {
            "1" : 5,
            "2":5
        },
        "2016" : {
            "1" : 5
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    '$group':
    {
        _id:{"O":"$O","D":"$D","Y":"$year"},
               "freq" :{$push: "$freq"}

    }
},
{
    '$group':
    {
        _id:{"O":"$O","D":"$D"},
               "freq" :{$push: "$freq"}

    }
})]
```

but I got an array without informations of year or month.

Thank you

Comment: Your JSON/sample docuemt is not valid !! It throws parse error as `Parse error on line 1: {^{ id: 111 ----` & even your expected output is not valid JSON.

Comment: Its still not valid JSON/BSON now.. `Error: Unable to prase JSON/BSON- Expecting 24 hex digits: 57614a, at (2, 31)`. With kind of question how do you expect people to spend time to answer ?

Comment: Are you putting the real data from production db? why don't you show us the real document from your mongodb collection? May be you question is not at all clear for anyone. Better you ask clear question

Comment: I putted the real one:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used two $group in your query

Your First group query is enough to build the data which you are expecting.

If we are executing the first query

```
db.stackoverflow.aggregate([
{
    '$group':
    {
        _id:{"O":"$O","D":"$D","Y":"$year"},
               "freq" :{$push: "$freq"}

    }
}]);
```

then the result is

```
{ "_id" : { "O" : "aa", "D" : "bb", "Y" : 2016 }, "freq" : [ 5 ] }
{ "_id" : { "O" : "aa", "D" : "bb", "Y" : 2015 }, "freq" : [ 5, 5 ] }
```

Now if you execute your second $group query

```
db.stackoverflow.aggregate([
{
    '$group':
    {
        _id:{"O":"$O","D":"$D"},
               "freq" :{$push: "$freq"}

    }
}])
```

then the result is

```
{ "_id" : { "O" : "aa", "D" : "bb" }, "freq" : [ 5, 5, 5 ] }
```

**Reason:**

The values fetched in the first $group query is not passed to the second $group query.

**Solution:**

Use **$project** available in the aggregation pipeline which passes along the documents with only the specified fields to the next stage in the aggregation pipeline. The specified fields can be existing fields from the input documents or newly computed fields.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

---

Here is the query to get your expected result

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$group': {
      _id: {
        "o": "$o",
        "d": "$d",
        "year": "$year"
      },
      myArr: {
        $push: {
          year: "$year",
          month: "$month",
          freq: "$freq"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      _id: {
        "o": "$o",
        "d": "$d"
      },
      myArr1: {
        $push: {
          year: "$year",
          freq: "$myArr"
        }
      }
    }
  },

],
{
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Comment: with $push you get an array without infromations on month. I'm looking for something like this :
`{    "_id" :  { "O" : "aa", "D" : "bb" }, "freq" :  {"2015" : { "1" : 5,  "2":5 },"2016" : {   "1" : 5  }   }}`
push an object
I can do $project after but I will not have informatiosn of number of month which I lost it in stage $group

Comment: try this query it will give you month and frequency. db.stackoverflow.aggregate([
{
    '$group':
    {
        _id:{"O":"$O","D":"$D","Y":"$year"}, myArr: {$push: {month: "$month", freq: "$freq" }}

    }
}])

Comment: Thank you but it works only for months when I try to group by only o and d and the push year. I got this error :
`Error: getMore command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "BSONObj size: 35028292 (0x2167D44) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)",
 "code" : 10334
}
`
I have many documents and I need to group by O and D

Comment: @MAYA - Post your query, let me debug it

Comment: here is my query :
`db.collection.aggregate([
{
 '$group':
 {
  _id:{"o":"$o","d":"$d","year":"$year"},
               myArr: {$push: {month: "$month", freq: "$freq" }}
            
 }
},
{
 '$group':
 {
  _id:{"o":"$o","d":"$d"},
               myArr1: {$push: {year: "$year", freq: "$myArr" }}
            
 }
},
],
{allowDiskUse:true}
)`
The example above is just a sample from my collection (980000 documents)

Comment: .   allowDiskUse: true
. })
ror: getMore command failed: {
      "ok" : 0,
      "errmsg" : "BSONObj size: 35028292 (0x2167D44) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)",
      "code" : 10334
I got this error (problem in size) :s

Comment: @MAYA -  MongoDB has 16MB limit. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/ we need to modify the  query, so that it is within size limit. Use $limit/$slice which ever applicable to retrieve less data.

Comment: By applying this, I will have just a part of my data that subject to size limit ?

Comment: @MAYA - we need to query again to retrieve the rest of the data. Since this 16MB limit is there in mongodb.

Comment: Ok I  get it. Thank you:)